# RegExp in JavaScript is returning null

Tags: javascript, regex

I want check phone numbers. Right format is 38xxxxxxxxxx.

My check:

```
var phoneNumber=document.getElementById('phone').value;
var re=new RegExp("^[38]\d{10}$");
var res=phoneNumber.match(re);
```

I always get null. What's wrong?

Comment: learn to use http://regex101.com before coming and asking, it will save you and everyone else a bunch of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the RegExp constructor function with quotes, normal string escape rules apply. Thus, you need to escape the special character `\d` as `\\d`. Also you need to change `[38]` to simply `38`, as `[38]` matches `3` or `8`.

```js
var str = '381234567890';

var re = new RegExp("^38\\d{10}$"); 
   // or new RegExp(/^38\d{10}$/); without quotes
   // or re = /^38\d{10}$/;

var res = str.match(re);

document.body.innerHTML = "Match result: " + res;
```

Answer (score 0):

var res=phoneNumber.match(/38[0-9]{8,10}/m);

phone number length allowed :10-12

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is wrong, if you want to match `38xxxxxxxxxx` you should remove `[]` brackets because this means `3` or `8` and afterwards it tries to match 10 digits, so just remove the `[]`

```
var re=new RegExp("^38\d{10}$");
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the constructor function, the normal string escape rules are necessary.

```
new RegExp("^38\\d{10}$");
```